# Apache can't access folders in my home directory

Tags: apache2

I have changed the configuration of Apache to point towards a folder in my home directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/dbugger/html

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/dbugger/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have even given my `/home/dbugger/html` permission 777. But I still keep getting the same error message at `http://localhost`: "403 Forbidden"

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: What about `/home/dbugger` permission?

Comment: You mean I should make 777 my whole home folder? That seems overdoing it. Even making 777 the html is not a safe solution. Im just doing it to try to identify the root of the problem.

Comment: apache runs as user www-data. If that user doesn't have executing permission on your home, apache will not be able to read any file.

Comment: Isn't there a way to add a subfolder of my home directory to the www-data wihtout having it to give complete access to the home folder? Following that logic seems like I would have to give access to ALL THE HOME folders as well, as I would have to give it access to /home. That seems too much

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This worked for me

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The important bit was to change

```
Order allow, deny
```

to

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: you save my time ,I don't have to change permission

Comment: Hi I'm glad that it helped you

Comment: I took the liberty of looking up what "require all granted" was and found that it is the "new equivalent" of `Allow from all` from apache 2.4 onwards - http://serverfault.com/questions/549517/what-does-apaches-require-all-granted-really-do

Comment: nope, granting access to the whole root is never a good idea!

Comment: Setting `AllowOverride` to `All` on your *root* directory is reckless at best! See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride for details.

Comment: thanks that saved lot of time, I tried other solutions before but only this worked

Comment: the path of this directory in ubuntu is  : etc/apache2/site-available

Comment: Is this added to the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file?

Answer (score 24):

#### Enable `userdir` module:

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

#### Enable PHP execution in user directory:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
```

(Or if using php7.0, for example)

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf
```

Comment this part (put `#` at the start of each line):

```
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save

#### Enable directory listing:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add this:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save

---

Restart apache (`sudo` required here also):

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now put your php files in `/home/yourname/public_html` directory and go to
 `http://localhost/~yourname` from your web browser.

Answer (score 17):

Apache runs as user `www-data`. If it doesn't have execution permission on your home, apache will not be able to read any file.

Change you home's group to `www-data`:

```
chgrp www-data /home/dbugger
```

And give it permission only to traverse your home directory:

```
chmod g+x /home/dbugger
```

You can also restrict permisions of `/home/dbugger/html`:

```
chgrp www-data /home/dbugger/html
chmod 750 /home/dbugger/html
```

Comment: Can I do that, but instead of `/home/dbugger` using `/home/dbugger/html`?

Comment: You can also apply that permission to `/home/dbugger/html` instead of 777, but you have to keep in mind that if user www-data cannot `cd` to your home, it won't be able to access any file or subfolder. So, if your home permission is `rwx------ dbugger:dbugger` apache will not be able to access any file inside your home. If you wan't to restrict access a little bit you could try giving only execute permission (`chmod g+x /home/dbugger`), I'm not sure, but I think it works.

Comment: Sorry but neither of this solutions did work :(

Comment: `chgrp www-data /home/dbugger` in combination with @DavidGreene method got it working for me

Comment: It's also possible to add your user group to the apache user (www-data) `sudo usermod -a -G dbugger www-data`, after that you need to restart apache.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need change the permissions if you want to use your home directory to host the development environment, at least that you need write permissions for some applications. You need apache mod_userdir module and you can access to /home/user_name/public_html/* like this http://domain.local/~user_name/dir_name/* for use a virtual hosts, to use the mod_userdir module you need create a sym link like this:

```
$ sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
$ sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: You can also use `a2enmod userdir`

Answer (score 0):

according to their page:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html

you can set userdir to something better:  /var/www
and create a directory in there by a "username", which you could make owned by a simple user, but world readable (i.e. 755), the user is required to copy files there, but it's a lot safer than making / or ~ world readable, etc.