# Running a subdomain site from user's home directory

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, sftp

I've got a question about Apache, run on an Ubuntu server. By default, my server stores all the web files that Apache serves at `/var/www/html`, within which I store the webroots of all the domains my server serves (using the `<VirtualHost>` protocol).

For one of my subdomains, I am trying to set `/home/%user&/example.com/htdocs` as a webroot, but it doesn't seem to be working. Apache is giving me a 403 error when I do that. I've tried changing ownership of `home/%user%` (both user and group) to `www-data`, but it doesn't work! `/home/%user%/example.com` is a `mount --bind` of `/var/www/html/example.com` folder, but the website itself seems to only work when I use `/var/www/html/example.com` instead of the former.

Any idea as to why? I'm putting the webroot into a user's home directory because I have jailed them to their home directory, since I don't want them to be snooping around the rest of my folders.

**P.S. This is not my main question, but I'll appreciate any insight on this too:** All the files in `/home/%user%/example.com` are owned by `%user%:%user%`, but even though Apache is running with `www-data:www-data`, it doesn't seem to have any problems reading and running `%user%:%user%`'s file. Is it because the read permissions of these files are all set to be allowed from all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the actual config?

This is likely caused by Apache not being configured to serve files out of /home; try `a2enmod userdir` to enable that set of permissions, and have a look at `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir` to see what does it (it'll be a `<Directory>` block and some `allow` directives).

If the site are using PHP you may need to edit `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*.conf` and comment out the line that disables PHP in home directories, too.

> /home/%user%/example.com are owned by %user%:%user%, but even though Apache is running with www-data:www-data, it doesn't seem to have any problems reading and running %user%:%user%'s file. Is it because the read permissions of these files are all set to be allowed from all users?

Yes; it's the 'all users' permissions there. Apache *reads* PHP files rather than executing them, as far as permissions are concerned.

Comment: Hi @BigRedS, thank you for chiming in. I have found an answer to my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325498/apache-cant-access-folders-in-my-home-directory). Couldn't have done it without your answer pointing me in the right direction!